# How to populate drop down using two dimension array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create two dimensional array and populate a dropdown using it.

But I'm getting  **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string** error.

```js
var cuisines = ["001","Australian"],["002","American"];     

var sel = document.getElementById('CuisineList');
for(var i = 0; i < cuisines.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = cuisines[i][1];
    opt.value = cuisines[i][0];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select id="CuisineList"></select>
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need outer brackets when defining your two dimensional array.

```
var cuisines = [["001","Australian"],["002","American"]];
```

Also, looks like you're using the letter "o" instead of the number 0 for one of your indexes.

Answer (score 2):

I did not investigate your code deeply but you have error:

```
 opt.value = cuisines[i][o];
```

should be

```
 opt.value = cuisines[i][0];
```

you are using "o" letter instead of 0 (zero)

Answer (score 2):

Change `var cuisines = ["001","Australian"],["002","American"];` to `var cuisines =[ ["001","Australian"],["002","American"]];` so you actually have a two dimensional array, and change your `[o]` to `[0]`.